# grouping same value from json using PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm new to PHP and I am reading data from external JSON file using PHP and I would like to group the same value (similar to Group by in MySQL). I have tried several ways and research but I could not get the expected result please help.

This is my JSON data:

```
[{"name":"jonh","school":"Barak Primary school","class":"3rd grade","year":"2019"},{"name":"Danny","school":"Barak Primary school","class":"4rd grade","year":"2019"},{"name":"Ben","school":"Mara Primary school","class":"3rd grade","year":"2019"}{"name":"West","school":"Mara Primary school","class":"3rd grade","year":"2019"}]
```

And this is my PHP

```
$json = file_get_contents('https://xxxx.json');//get data from url
$posts = json_decode($json,true); // put data into variable 
foreach ($posts as $val) {
     echo '<p>' . $val[school] . '</p>';
}
```

And this is result I got:

```
Barak Primary School
Barak Primary School
Mara Primary School
Mara Primary School
```

But I want the result like this:

```
Barak Primary School
Mara Primary School
```

So in this case it grouped the same value into one, all your suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`array_column`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-column.php) to extract the `school` values from your `JSON`, and then [`array_unique`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) to find only the distinct values. You can then loop over those values:

```
$schools = array_unique(array_column($posts, 'school'));
foreach ($schools as $school) {
    echo '<p>' . $school . '</p>';
}
```

Output:

```
<p>Barak Primary school</p><p>Mara Primary school</p>
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/v03Ds)